# ASP.NET AJAX or jQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We are in the company starting a new product, we choose to use ASP.NET MVC 4.
I know that it's in the beta state.

We are going to outsource the UI.
We cannot decide what UI technology to use:

Should it be  jQuery or ASP.NET AJAX like DevExpress or something.

Could you please give me several reasons what is better for a new product.
I am not a web developer so please explain in appropriate manner.

Thanks .

Comment: What kind of answers are you expecting to get?

Comment: MVC 4 is not in BETA. if you see the Sctipts folder jQuery and microsoft ajax already there. so you can use it. and if you are not a web developer, better to learn it before start the product.

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal: If you take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 right now, it looks pretty much like MVC 4 is in beta.

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal MVC4 is in beta but includes a 'Go Live' license so it can be used in production. I don't believe there has been any mention of a release date yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### jQuery, hands down

Whatever you do **please don't use Asp.net AJAX**. It's bloated and Microsoft has favoured jQuery ever since. Asp.net AJAX has been written to *fast switch* WebForms to modern AJAX applications. But we all know that was more or less a huge failure. MVC on the other hand is a web platform built on top of HTTP and with HTTP in its mind. Writing stateless pages using either everyday HTTP requests or AJAX ones makes it equally simple. There's no need to use something bloated that was written for WebForms and not MVC.

Just use jQuery because it's much more widely used, gets frequently updated, extended, upgraded and is extremely simple and well documented.

There are **many many many more users using jQuery** than any other Javascript library so getting "support" is much simpler and faster than getting it with other libraries.

And when you decide to use some third party plugins/controls etc. I would be very hesitant. Those companies usually create very convincing marketing-oriented copywriting. But in the end I've mostly experienced nightmare. There're open source alternatives and very active ones as well. Not to mention jQuery UI components that will make your UI much more maintainable (user base again) and no price bound to particular vendor.

If this is your first app on Asp.net MVC, you should switch your mind set from WebForms and some rich third party server controls you used to use in WebForms. It's more often that these are **not used** in MVC than the other way around. They were providing arguably better UI in WebForms, but I tend to rather keep away from them in MVC. Avoid additional abstractions...

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a new MVC project you get jQuery included in the base setup. All client side data validation in MVC3 (I guess the same is true for MVC4) is based on jQuery Validate. Without jQuery you would loose a major functionality for any forms for user input.

As far as I know ASP.NET AJAX is built as custom controls for web forms. Web forms controls are not compatible with MVC.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

ASP.NET MVC4 is built with jQuery in mind. Microsoft, I believe, has given up on developing their own AJAX libraries. Regardless they are focused on Web Forms not MVC. MVC4 actually installs jQuery and jQuery UI (MVC4) when you create a new project in Visual Studio. It also includes Intellisense for jQuery. All the validation is also built around jQuery and is integrated with jQuery's very popular validation plugin. MVC4 also includes support for jQuery mobile. Additionally all the sample sites I've seen are built with jQuery in mind. Furthermore you mention outsourcing the UI. Microsoft also publishes jQuery on their content delivery network which I think indicates their commitment to it. Finally if you go with jQuery you won't need to worry about going with a Microsoft shop for your UI development. The UI should be agnostic which you don't really get with Microsoft's AJAX.

I wouldn't think about developing a new MVC site built on ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

My choice would be jQuery. I am currently implementing that with my product.

A great [article](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2010/01/27/mvc-or-webforms/) has been written about MVC vs. Webforms. I hope this sheds light on what your company wants to move forward with.